# How to check if setChoiceModel is not null?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I want to create a effect that if the `checkbox` of the `ListView` is checked, the string will be underlined. However I am not sure how to check if the `checkbox` is not null, or is check?
Is there any build in method to do it?

```
fieldToEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.todoEditText);
listToView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewOfItems);

final ArrayAdapter<String> adpt=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, ar);
listToView.setAdapter(adpt);
listToView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check listview item in CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE

use methods:

[setItemChecked (int position, boolean value)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked%28int,%20boolean%29)

[isItemChecked (int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#isItemChecked%28int%29)

[getCheckedItemPosition ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemPosition%28%29)

Use can use more methods provided in the link.

Answer (score 1):

To check if given object reference is not null you usually do:

```
if ( mChecbox != null ) {
   ...
}
```

To check if checkbox is checked you call:

```
if( mCheckbox.isChecked() ) {
   ...
}
```

where `mCheckbox` is value returned by `findViewById()`.